# Node js npm installed global package cannot be called from terminal, tried everything

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, bash

I have installed some `node js` packages globally on my MAC.

I run `$sudo npm install -g jshint` in my terminal at my root directory which is `/Users/apple/`.

And I try to run `$jshint myfile.js`, but only got this error:

```
-bash: jshint: command not found
```

I have tried everything :

1. added `NODE_PATH="/Users/apple/npm-global/lib/node_modules"`
2. Changed `$sudo chown apple /Users/apple/npm-global/`
3. Changed `$sudo chown apple /Users/apple`
4. Changed `$sudo chown apple /Users/apple/Tutorial/Nodejs/myfile.js`

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

EDIT
--------------------------------------

So I have reinstalled node js using brew, and I followed all the default folders which is `usr/local/` , but still, `$npm -g ls shows /usr/local/lib` and my jshint package is successfully installed in `/usr/local/lib`, run `$jshint, "-bash: jshint: command not found"...`

Comment: Are other node packages found?

Comment: @Jordan S no, only $node works...

Answer (score 0):

run the following to see where global libraries are installed

```
npm list -g
```

Comment: The result is : /Users/apple/npm-global/lib

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use `sudo` with `npm`. If you can, uninstall npm and install it again with a simple `brew install` without sudo. Nevertheless, if you do not want to use Homebrew, npm has a [guide](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) for fixing issues like this.

`npm config get prefix`

will give you the npm's directory. If it's not /usr/local (the default on macOS), change it:

`npm config set prefix /usr/local`

Ultimately, if nothing works for you, you could try to `chown` npm's folder to your user.

Edit: If you want to keep the path `/Users/apple/npm-global` as your default npm path, you're going to have to add it to your `$PATH` global variable.

`vi ~/.bash_profile`

Append this command: `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/apple/npm-global` and then make sure to save the file.

Run this to apply the changes immediately: `source ~/.bash_profile`

Finally, verify that your path has been succesfully added: `echo $PATH`

Comment: Run $npm config get prefix, result is : /Users/apple/npm-global and I want it to be  /Users/apple/npm-global actually, can I still have  /Users/apple/npm-global and make it work??

Comment: Have you tried to chown it? `sudo chown apple: /Users/apple/npm-global`

Comment: Tried $sudo chown apple: /Users/apple/npm-global, still -bash: jshint: command not found

Comment: Also, obviously make sure this directory is specified in your`PATH` global variable.

Comment: And I tried $brew install node, got the same error: -bash: brew: command not found

Comment: Run $ echo $PATH, result is:
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/Users/apple/npm-global/. So it is added, but still not working......WTF

Comment: See this in order to install Homebrew: http://brew.sh/ . Make sure you uninstall node before running `brew install node`

Comment: reinstalled node using homebrew, run node command works fine, still can't run jshint...